# How should I do to inverse Laplace transform without table?

Tags: inverse-laplace

Can I use integration method like fourier transform? How should I integral

$$ f(p)=\frac a {p^2+a^2}$$ to inverse it to $\sin(at)$ ?

Comment: Yes, you basically apply the (inverse) Fourier transform with the axis shifted so the integral converges. But it is a lot slower than tables.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.